# How to modify the cocoapods-Xcode-plugin install command?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

Default is pod install but I can not use this command.

Need to be modified for pod install--verbose--no-repo-update can be used.

Answer (score 0):

pod install --verbose --no-repo-update

or

pod update --verbose --no-repo-update
[image]